# How to split spark DataFrame while sending to kafka?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am using the following statement to write my dataframe to kafka.

```
dataFrame.write.format("kafka")
    .options(options).save()
```

Unfortunately above code is writing huge dataframe into kafka as single message, which is causing multiple issues, I want kafka to send a single data frame divided into multiple messages, also I dont want to send msg by msg for each records. I want to send as chunks which my kafka server should easily accepts without changing any configs in server side, please dont suggest to split using rownum, which I can do myself. Is there any builtin option in spark to divide while sending to kafka?

Comment: What do you have in expression dictate what's written to kafka as message.
Reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#deploying

Comment: If expression is the issue, lets leave that.. I have removed it. is there a way to split dataFrame while writing to kafka?